# Parse logs in Logstash or filebeat and transform them as JSON to pull Elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using filbeat to send logs to logstash and then store them in elasticsearch.

My logs file contains string like these:

```
MESSAGE: { "url": "http://IP:PORT/index.html" , "msg": "aaa" }
MESSAGE: { "url": "http://IP:PORT/index_2.html" , "msg": "bbb" }
```

I would like to store in Elasticsearch just the JSON object.
I am struggling in using some regex in order to parse the data and then transform them in JSON to send to an index to Elasticsearch.
Any help? should I put the logic to stripout "MESSAGE :"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your message, one part with just `MESSAGE:`, that you can ignore, and another one with the `json`, which you will then send to a `json` filter.

Try the following:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "MESSAGE:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:json_message}"
    }
    json {
        source => "json_message"
    } 
}
```

This will get your original message and apply a `grok` filter to only get the json part in a field called `json_message`, then the `json` filter will parse this field and create the fields `url` and `msg` for each event.